# Пропадает подключение в Ubuntu Server на VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, сеть, virtualbox

У меня работает Ubuntu Server на виртуальной машине (VirtualBox). Хост-пк я время от времени перевожу в спящий режим (при этом виртуальная машина работает, не приостановлена), но про пробуждении пк, на Ubuntu Server полностью пропадает соединение с интернетом.

При перезапуске появляется "Wait for network to be Configured", которое не исчезает пока я не отключу сеть (в настройках VB) и не подключу опять.

Что с этим делать?

Comment: 1. поискать сообщение об этой ошибке в [баг-трекере virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker). 2. если не найдётся — создать новое.